# activar animaciones al hacer scroll hacia arriba y hacia abajo. cuando la animacion se ve en pantalla

Tags: jquery, html5, css3, animación

```js
$(function() {

  var $window           = $(window),
      win_height_padded = $window.height() * 1.1,
      isTouch           = Modernizr.touch;

  if (isTouch) { $('.revealOnScroll').addClass('animated'); }

  $window.on('scroll', revealOnScroll);

  function revealOnScroll() {
    var scrolled = $window.scrollTop(),
        win_height_padded = $window.height() * 1.1;

    // Showed...
    $(".revealOnScroll:not(.animated)").each(function () {
      var $this     = $(this),
          offsetTop = $this.offset().top;
         /* offsetBottom = $this.offset().top;
*/
      if (scrolled + win_height_padded > offsetTop) {
        if ($this.data('timeout')) {
          window.setTimeout(function(){
            $this.addClass('animated ' + $this.data('animation'));
          }, parseInt($this.data('timeout'),10));
        } else {
          $this.addClass(' ' + $this.data('animation'));
        }
      }
    });
    // Hidden...
   $(".revealOnScroll.animated").each(function (index) {
      var $this     = $(this),
          offsetTop = $this.offset().top;
      if (scrolled + win_height_padded < offsetTop) {
        $(this).removeClass('animated text-animation icon-size');
     
      }
    });
  }

  revealOnScroll();
});
```

```css
.space
{
  height:1200px;
}
.box
{
  background-color: grey;
  padding:100px;
}

.text-animation
{
  max-width:360px;
}


.animatable {
  
  /* initially hide animatable objects */
  visibility: hidden;
  
  /* initially pause animatable objects their animations */
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;   
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;     
  -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;   
  animation-play-state: paused; 
}



/* show objects being animated */
.animated {
  visibility: visible;
  
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
  -o-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;

  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
  -moz-animation-play-state: running;
  -ms-animation-play-state: running;
  -o-animation-play-state: running;
  animation-play-state: running;

  
}


@-webkit-keyframes movimiento-diagonal {
   from {
      left: -800px;
   }
   
   to {
      left: 10px;
   }
}   

.text-animation {
   -webkit-animation-name: movimiento-diagonal;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -webkit-animation-direction: normal;/*para que vuelva a su posicion inicial */

   position: relative;
   padding: 2px;
} 


ul
{
  list-style: none;
  line-height:3em;
}



/* increase size fontawesome icons with keyframes*/

@-webkit-keyframes size-icons {
   0% {
      font-size: 0;
   }
   
   100% {
      font-size: 3.5em;
   }
}   


.icon-size{
   -webkit-animation-name: size-icons;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  /* -webkit-animation-iteration-count: ;*/
   -webkit-animation-direction: normal;/*para que vuelva a su posicion inicial */

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="a" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 

 </head>


<body>

<div class="container">
<h1>texto en movimiento</h1>
<div class="space">
</div>  
  <div class="box row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <p data-animation="text-animation" data-timeout="400" class=" revealOnScroll">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A doloremque quam dicta aperiam hic ab est tempora pariatur harum placeat, corrupti et! Incidunt, nemo perferendis delectus autem alias voluptas cupiditate.</p>
  </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <ul>
        <li><i data-animation="icon-size" data-timeout="400" class="fa fa-arrow-down  animatable revealOnScroll" aria-hidden="true"></i>
primer elemento</li>
        <li><i data-animation="icon-size" data-timeout="400" class="fa fa-arrow-down  animatable revealOnScroll" aria-hidden="true"></i>
segundo elemento</li>
        <li><i data-animation="icon-size" data-timeout="400" class="fa fa-arrow-down  animatable revealOnScroll" aria-hidden="true"></i>
tercer elemento</li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
    </div>
 <div class="space">
</div>   
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

no funciona la animacion por un error al cargar modernizr que no consigo solucionar pero lo que quiero hacer es que la animación se active al aparecer en pantalla ya se haga scroll hacia abajo o hacia arriba.